# OOF not working - Server Error in '/EWS' Application

Tags: outlook-2010, exchange-server-2010

We are trying to configure OOF on an Exchange Server. We are talking about Outlook 2010 with Exchange server 2010.

If i navigate to https://mail.[server]/ews/exchange.asmx i see the following page:

Server Error in '/EWS' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

I already recreated EWS, OWA and OAB, without any effect.

There is no proxy active in the organisation.

There are no internet restrictions.

Help

Comment: Current error message:

Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
...

Comment: ...
Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Comment: New error message:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCustomString' to type 'System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCompiledType'.